# Issue in installation of mxnet package in R

Tags: r, installation, mxnet

`mxnet` package is not installing in r (on windows 10) when I follow the steps given in its documentation.

```
install.packages("drat", repos="https://cran.rstudio.com")
drat:::addRepo("dmlc")
install.packages("mxnet")
```

It gives the following result

> Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Ashish/Documents/R/win-library/3.3’
>   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified) Warning in install.packages :   cannot open
>   URL 'http://dmlc.github.io/drat/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/PACKAGES.gz':
>   HTTP status was '404 Not Found' Warning in install.packages :   cannot
>   open URL
>   'http://dmlc.github.io/drat/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/PACKAGES': HTTP
>   status was '404 Not Found' Warning in install.packages :   unable to
>   access index for repository
>   http://dmlc.github.io/drat/bin/windows/contrib/3.3:   cannot open URL
>   'http://dmlc.github.io/drat/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/PACKAGES' Package
>   which is only available in source form, and may need   compilation of
>   C/C++/Fortran: ‘mxnet’ Do you want to attempt to install these from
>   sources? y/n: y installing the source package ‘mxnet’
>
> trying URL 'http://dmlc.github.io/drat/src/contrib/mxnet_0.5.tar.gz'
>   Warning in install.packages :   cannot open URL
>   'http://dmlc.github.io/drat/src/contrib/mxnet_0.5.tar.gz': HTTP status
>   was '404 Not Found' Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode
>   = "wb", ...) :    cannot open URL 'http://dmlc.github.io/drat/src/contrib/mxnet_0.5.tar.gz' Warning in
>   install.packages :   download of package ‘mxnet’ failed

Kindly help me resolve this issue. I'm using R version 3.3.0. Is there any other way of installing it in R?

Comment: Seems like the issue is resolved on Windows 10 now.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to install it successfully by first downloading its zip file from the following link

https://github.com/dmlc/drat/tree/gh-pages/bin/windows/contrib/3.2

and then installing it using RStudio.

I hope this answer will help anyone else facing the same problem.

Comment: The link is now dead

Comment: can you please take a look at my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65495946/r-namespace-load-failed-for-mxnet-package-mxnet-was-installed-before-r-4-0

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and was able to resolve it by following the instructions on this page and choosing the correct OS, Language and CPU/GPU options:
http://mxnet.io/get_started/install.html

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO! Link only answers are discouraged here because if the page changes or goes offline your answer will be invalidated. Better to update your answer with the relevant sections from the page and link to it as a source for your answer

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that worked for me was to download the mxnet.zip file to a folder, (set it as working directory) and type:

```
install.packages("mxnet.zip", repos=NULL, type="win.binary")
```

Comment: can you please take a look at my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65495946/r-namespace-load-failed-for-mxnet-package-mxnet-was-installed-before-r-4-0

Answer (score 0):

You can try using different repo  in `repos`.

Otherwise you can download the [drat](https://github.com/dmlc/mxnet/issues/1085) package along with dependencies and install manually.

Check if these URLs are accessible from your machine or not.

Following links will be helpful for you:
http://mxnet-bing.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html#r-package-installation
https://github.com/dmlc/mxnet/issues/1085

Answer (score 0):

The more up-to-date **Installation Guide** is currently located here:
http://mxnet.io/get_started/setup.html#installing-mxnet

I found the paragraph about the installation of the R-package on Windows to be very well written.

By the way, the `install.packages("mxnet")` command installs a very long tool chain, so it might happen that a package is currently not indexed correctly in the dmlc-repo (i.e. because it was just updated to a newer version on CRAN): `Error: package <pkgname> is not available for R version 3.3.1` So you might want to install the "offending" package from the CRAN (or download the sourcecode and use something like `install.packages(file.choose(), repos = NULL, type = "source")`), then continue with another call to `install.packages("mxnet")`.

Answer (score 0):

try these commands to install mxnet package:--

```
cran <- getOption("repos")
cran["dmlc"] <- "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/apache-mxnet/R/CRAN/"
options(repos = cran)
install.packages("mxnet")
```