# MXNet package installation in R

Tags: r, package, mxnet

I get plenty of trouble when trying to install **MXNet** package in R
I am using the 3.4.0 version of R and I am on windows 10 CPU intel i3, 64bits  x64-based processor.

I get prompted:

```
install.packages("mxnet")
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/src/contrib/PACKAGES.rds': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/los40/OneDrive/Documentos/R/win-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘mxnet’ is not available (for R version 3.4.0)
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/PACKAGES.rds': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
```

I've tried downloading the .rar files provided here. I decompress one and get the folder where it says "R package" attempting to install it by using:

```
> install.packages('R.package.rar', lib='D:/mxnet',repos = NULL)
Error in install.packages : type == "both" cannot be used with 'repos = NULL'
> install.packages('R.package.rar', lib='D:/mxnet')
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘R.package.rar’ is not available (for R version 3.4.0)
```

The guide found in http://mxnet.io/get_started/windows_setup.html makes no sense to me since I cannot find the file required in the steps for installing the prebuild package on windows called **setupenv.cmd**

Comment: Previously asked and answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37110169/issue-in-installation-of-mxnet-package-in-r

Comment: Ye, I've been checking that post and I can't get the solution

Comment: Have you tried : install.packages("drat", repos="https://cran.rstudio.com")
drat:::addRepo("dmlc")
install.packages("mxnet")

Comment: It tells me "drat" is not available for 3.4.0 version

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For `mxnet` package install in R using this command for only CPU

```
cran <- getOption("repos")
cran["dmlc"] <- "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/apache-mxnet/R/CRAN/"
options(repos = cran)
install.packages("mxnet",dependencies = T)
library(mxnet)
```

Comment: Getting `cannot open URL 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/apache-mxnet/R/CRAN/src/contrib/mxnet_1.3.0.tar.gz': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'`

Comment: Most likely the package is no longer available at that link.

Comment: Can you please take a look at my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65495946/r-namespace-load-failed-for-mxnet-package-mxnet-was-installed-before-r-4-0 thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following line:

```
cran <- getOption("repos")
cran["dmlc"] <- "https://s3.amazonaws.com/mxnet-r/"
options(repos = cran)
install.packages("mxnet")
```

Comment: I get this: > install.packages("mxnet", repos="https://dmlc.ml/drat/")
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/src/contrib/PACKAGES.rds': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/los40/OneDrive/Documentos/R/win-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: 'The host name in the certificate is invalid or does not match'
Warning in install.packages :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: 'The host name in the certificate is invalid or does not match...

Comment: trying URL 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/mxnet-r/src/contrib/mxnet_0.10.1.tar.gz'
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/mxnet-r/src/contrib/mxnet_0.10.1.tar.gz': HTTP status was '403 Forbidden'
Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
  cannot open URL 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/mxnet-r/src/contrib/mxnet_0.10.1.tar.gz'
Warning in install.packages :
  download of package ‘mxnet’ failed

Answer (score -1):

For windows, if you want to install `mxnet`. Use the below commmand:

```
cran <- getOption("repos")
cran["dmlc"] <- "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/apache-mxnet/R/CRAN/"
options(repos = cran)
install.packages("mxnet",dependencies = T)
library(mxnet)
```